# ISBN show that $x_{10}=\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I want to show that for a ISBN-number $x_1x_2...x_{10}$ that satisfies $\sum^{10}_{i=1} ix_i\equiv 0 \mod 11$ the last digit must be $x_{10}=\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i \mod 11$

---

My attempt:

$$11\cdot \sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i \equiv 0 \mod 11 \tag 1$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i + 10 \underbrace{\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i}_{=x_{10}} \equiv 0 \mod 11 \tag 2$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum^{10}_{i=1} ix_i \equiv 0 \mod 11\tag 3$$
Therefore,
$$x_{10}=\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i \tag 4$$
But I'm a little confused why $x_{10} = \sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i \mod 11$. It actually doesn't have to be. Or do we need to specify this only because $x_{10}\in \{0,...,10\}$?

Comment: how to you come from (2) to (3)?

Comment: @miracle173 $\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i + 10x_{10} = \sum^{10}_{i=1} ix_i$

Comment: that is correct, that follows from the definition of the $\Sigma$ symbol. But that does not answer my question how you derive (3) from (2).

Comment: Well (2) and (3) is the same thing, just with $x_{10}=\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i$ and simplified, isn't it? So the congruence is still $0\mod 11$

Comment: now, (2) and (3) is definitely not the same thing. With your underbrace you say that $x_{10}=\sum^{9}_{i=1} ix_i$. But why? this is what you should prove. You cannot use ist as precondition of your proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} ix_i \equiv 0 \mod 11$$

$$10x_{10}+\sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \equiv 0 \mod 11$$

$$11x_{10}-x_{10}+\sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \equiv 0 \mod 11$$

$$-x_{10}+\sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \equiv 0 \mod 11$$

$$x_{10} \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{9} ix_i \mod 11$$

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't see this earlier